# Custom time format not works in tmux

Tags: tmux

Refer to the [document](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#FORMATS):

> Prefixing a time variable with ‘t:’ will convert it to a string, so
> if ‘#{window_activity}’ gives ‘1445765102’, ‘#{t:window_activity}’
> gives ‘Sun Oct 25 09:25:02 2015’.  Adding ‘p (’ ‘`t/p`’) will use
> shorter but less accurate time format for times in the past.  A
> custom format may be given using an ‘f’ suffix (note that ‘%’ must
> be escaped as ‘%%’ if the format is separately being passed through
> strftime(3), for example in the status-left option):
> ‘#{t/f/%%H#:%%M:window_activity}’, see strftime(3).

My tmux version is 3.1c. `{t:window_activity}` showed the correct time format, but `{t/p:window_activity}` and `{t/f/%%H#:%%M:window_activity}` showed empty. Are there additional settings needed to make the custom time format work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a mistake to use documentation that does not correspond to your release. The man page for 3.1c does not mention these options, because they were not implemented until 3.2.

You can browse the source man page on [github](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/tmux.1#L4746); it has the latest documention and line 4746 shows the options. Clicking on *blame* will show the origin of this line [here (beware heavy page for browser)](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blame/master/tmux.1#L4746), and clicking on the left url brings us to the change [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/106e5d07beaacaa977372f8b6a0bcac5f981545b), where the tag shown is [3.2](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/releases/tag/3.2).

So, to avoid problems, please use `man tmux` provided with the release in use, rather than just pages found on the internet.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice the version of the document!